# How to concat with condition in Spark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For example, raw dataframe is as follows:

```
+--------+--------+
|    col1|    col2|
+--------+--------+
|    null|       A|
|       B|    null|
|       C|       D|
|    null|    null|
+--------+--------+
```

I want to concat the `col1` and `col2` to get the following dataframe:

```
+--------+--------+-------------------+
|    col1|    col2|               col3|
+--------+--------+-------------------+
|    null|       A|         "{col2:A}"|
|       B|    null|         "{col1:B}"|
|       C|       D| "{col1:C, col2:D}"|
|    null|    null|               "{}"|
+--------+--------+-------------------+
```

The new `col3` is concatenated by non-null `col1` and non-null `col2`. And col3 is string type. How to add the null condition to the concat method?

Comment: what if col1 and col2 both are null?

Comment: I have changed the question, if col1 and col2 are both null, the col3 will be `{}`.

Comment: what is {} ? is it a string or a dictionary? can you share the expected dataframe schema?

Comment: {} is a string. col3 is string type. You can think the col3 `{col2:A}` is `"{col2:A}"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine columns into an array

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val  df = Seq((null, "A"), ("B", null), ("C", "D"), (null, null)).toDF("colA", "colB")

val cols = array(df.columns.map(c =>
  // If column is not null, merge it with its name otherwise null
  when(col(c).isNotNull, concat_ws(":", lit(c), col(c)))): _*
)
```

and use `UserDefinedFunction`

```scala
val combine = udf((xs: Seq[String]) => {
   val tmp = xs.filter { _ != null }.mkString(",")
   s"{$tmp}"
})

df.withColumn("col3", combine(cols)).show
// +----+----+---------------+
// |colA|colB|           col3|
// +----+----+---------------+
// |null|   A|       {colB:A}|
// |   B|null|       {colA:B}|
// |   C|   D|{colA:C,colB:D}|
// |null|null|             {}|
// +----+----+---------------+
```

Comment: What if the column types are different, I want to filter the `null` and `"null"`, then how to write the code `when(col(c).isNotNull and col(c) != "null")`?

Comment: `when(coalesce(col(c).isNotNull , col(c) =!= "null"),  ...)`?

Comment: Not this mean. The dataframe's columns are different, the float type is filtered by `.isNotNull`, but the string type column in my dataframe should be filtered by `!="null"`, how to make it?

Comment: `null` is `null`, not matter the type. I am not sure if I understand the problem. But `coalesce` should work if you have literal `"null"` string. Or you can `when(col(c).isNotNull  and  (col(c) <=> "null"), ...)`?

Comment: Yes, I have both literal `"null"` and `null`. When I write `when(coalesce(col(c).isNotNull , col(c) != "null"), ...)`, it tells me`type mismatch, found boolean, required: Column`; but when  I write `when(coalesce(col(c).isNotNull , col(c) =!= "null"), ...)`, it works. What is the difference between `=!=` and `!=`?